# Getting lookup which contains fields from multiple tables

Tags: axapta, lookup, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I have 3 tables Ram , Sam , Dun

Ram Table has fields

RAMItemCode  RamItemDescription RamItemStatus(Active/Inactive)   Recid

R1             Rest1              Active                         RRec1

R2             Rest2              Inactive                       RRec2

R3             Rest3              Active                         RRec3

Sam Table has fields

SamItem       SamStatus        Recid

s1            Active           srec1

s2            Active           srec2

S3            Inactive         srec3

Dun Table has 3 fields

Sam          Ram          Status

Srec1        RRec1        Active    -(As both s1 and r1 are active this is active)

Srec1        RRec2        Inactive   (As s1 is active and r2 is inactive this is inactiv)

Srec2        RRec1        Active      (As both S2, R1 are active)

Srec2        RRec3        Active      (As both S2 and R3 are active)

If both are active in Sam field and Ram field in Table Dun then only status will be active in Dun table status field. Else it will always be inactive if atleeast one of Sam or Ram is inactive .  -- Rule

If i change status either in Ram table or SAm table the corresponding fields status will also be changed as per Rule in Dun Table.

Now i have two fields

Sam -

Ram -

in a form which is a unbound control.

I am getting lookup for Sam field from SAM Table. Now i selected Sam field from lookup of Sam master.
Now in the second field ram i need to get lookup of RamItemCode which is related to the sam selected in first field and status from DUN Table.

Dun Table has 3 fields

Sam          Ram          Status

Srec1        RRec1        Active      -(As both s1 and r1 are active this is active)

Srec1        RRec2        Inactive    (As s1 is active and r2 is inactive this is inactiv)

Srec2        RRec1        Active      (As both S2, R1 are active)

Srec2        RRec3        Active      (As both S2 and R3 are active)

For Example :  If i select S1 in first field on form. The Ram lookup should contain R1,R2 as shown in above table Srec1 has RRec1,RRec2 related with status as Active and Inactive. So i need to show in lookup RAMItemCOde for RRec1,RRec2 along with status(Status from DUn table)  Like as shown below.
Sam: S1

Ram:   R1  Active

```
   R2  Inactive.
```

Thats my scenario. Can you please help me. Thanks in advance. Hope this is clear enough. Let me know if any more info needed. Thanks.

Comment: By `tab3` you mean `rel`?

Comment: This does not make sense: One field from tab2 can have multiple records from tab1. Also the second bullet "Now in the ..." is unclear.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example with some actual data to make your requirements easier to understand?

Answer (score 1):

Let me first rephrase your question to make sure I understood: Tables `Ram` and `Sam` have a n:m relationship defined by table `Dun`. In your first lookup you select a value from table `Sam`. Your second lookup should now show all possible values from table `Ram` as well as the Status field from table `Dun`. So basically you want to do a lookup on one table (`Dun`) but the return value should come from another table (`Ram`).

You can achieve this with the following code in the lookup method of the form control of your second lookup field. But first you need to download and Import an xpo by Ivan Kashperuk that will give you the new class [SysMultiTableLookup](http://kashperuk.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/sysmultitableloookup-dynamic-lookups.html). You also should set the property `AutoDeclaration` of your first lookup control (named `SamLookup` in my code) to "Yes". Now you can now write the following code:

```
public void lookup()
{
    Sam                  sam;
    Query                query = new Query();
    QueryBuildDataSource qbds;
    QueryBuildRange      queryBuildRange;
    SysTableLookup       sysTableLookup;
    SysMultiTableLookup  sysMultiTableLookup;

    // retrieve the RecId of the Ram record selected in the first lookup
    select firstOnly RecId from sam where sam.ItemCode == samLookup.valueStr();

    // build the query on the relation table Dun joined to the Sam table and filtered
    // to the records available for the selected Ram record
    qbds = query.addDataSource(tableNum(Dun));
    qbds.addRange(fieldNum(Dun, Sam)).value(queryValue(sam.RecId));
    qbds = qbds.addDataSource(tableNum(Ram));
    qbds.relations(true);

    // Build the lookup
    sysMultiTableLookup = SysMultiTableLookup::newParameters(this, query);
    sysMultiTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldNum(Dun, Status));
    sysMultiTableLookup.addLookupField(fieldNum(Ram, ItemCode), 2, true); // 2 for second data source of query, true to use this field as return value of lookup

    sysMultiTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

[Example xpo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_8-f_RHx2SmMzczWnNFOVJIblk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi When i imported the SysMultitablelookup code it gave me an error saying addlookupmethod parameter _label should have a default value. So i made it as addLookupMethod( xxx,xxx , _label = ""). And i added the code as you said but when i click on lookup its not opening. samlookup.valueStr() value is recid of service we selected on first lookup.  I am not getting any lookup. The dropdown is not opening.Can you help me. Thanks.

Comment: @Raas: Sorry for the delay, I had some trouble with my VM where I implemented an example. I attached the example as xpo to my answer, please take a look and compare it with your own implementation. If that does not help you, maybe you could upload a xpo of your implementation so I could take a look at it?

Comment: Also take a look at the answers of the following question, they propose using a view to solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659999/how-to-create-a-lookup-with-fields-from-more-than-one-datasource?rq=1

Comment: Hi Sure i will give you more clarification by today or tomorrow. I am still not able to fix that issue.